# Casting pointers into long

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, long-integer

I'm working with JNI (developing for Android using Native code).

The case is I would like to send to a Java Class a pointer to a Native object. For that I've seen in casting the pointer direction into a long, like this:

```
long pointerDirection = (long)pointer;
```

Is this secure? I've read that in some architectures, a 'long' is just 32 bits, but the pointers just need 32 bits, right? Or in 64 bits they also use 64 bits?

Thanks

Comment: If you are concerned that the width of type can change, why not choose a fixed width type like `uint64_t` and if you want native pointer type just go for `intptr_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this secure?

No, definitely not – the standard makes no such guarantee (even though it may work on many machines in practice).

You can cast it safely (only) to the integral type `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: How would the `ptrdiff_t` then be passed to Java?. If he wants to pass the pointer to Java he can `reinterpret_cast` to `jlong`